# Determining sets of substrings in a list of strings

Tags: python, string

Okay, please forgive me for my question, it's probably not asked in the best way possible!!

I have a set of 56 entries in a dictionary. The keys indicate the combinations of features that are represented by the strings in the dictionaries. I am subdividing the dictionary of strings into sets based on features and putting the values into lists. My code works up until this point.

I am now having difficulties working out how I compare each of the strings in the list to each other to find out what the maximum shared string is. So my lists look like:

[ngali, ngali, ngalina, ngalina, ngina, ngina, nginana]

So 'ng' is what I'm after in this case.  So far I've only been able to find reference to finding string distances with things like Levinshtein, and fuzz.

Are there any 'neat' ways of coding this or am I destined to write nested loops nested in loops to work through all of the possible combinations?

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: It looks like you're implementing a variation of the Longest Common Substring problem (with your substring at the front it seems). Perhaps this would be of use? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Python_3

Comment: So I had read through that earlier and correct me if I'm wrong, but that code snippet only finds the longest common substring if it starts at the start of the word, in my case it may be anywhere in the word. I'm guessing I'm going to have to create another for loop in that to account for a sliding start point...

Answer (score -1):

```
from os.path import commonprefix
l = ['ngali','ngali','ngalina','ngalina','ngina','ngina','nginana']
commonprefix(l)
```

Comment: I'm not just looking for common prefixes, I need to be able to find the longest common string regardless of where it is in the word.  In another set I'll have to look at words like ['ngalina' , 'nginana'] and find the 'na', in other cases the string will be in the centre of the word.

Comment: @Ant you wanted 'ng'; at least have the courtesy not to downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote, I don't know who downvoted. At least I don't think I did, I'm new to this, so if I did, I apologise.

Comment: So I just checked and it wasn't me who downvoted, I don't have the required number of reputation points (15) to be able to vote on anything yet, so I'm afraid it was someone else.

Comment: Yep, I've looked at that as well, I'm working on coding it up at the moment and leaving the question open for when my code fails spectacularly in about an hour and I need some more help :)

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but it's probably good to include a little more context/explanation as "code-only" answers tend to be frowned upon.